# Singularity of inverse exponential integral function

Tags: co.combinatorics, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, cv.complex-variables, asymptotics, singularity-theory

The exponential integral function is defined by

$$ Ei(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z dw \frac{e^w}{w} \,.$$

Away from the negative real axis the exponential integral function has a Taylor series about $z=0$:

$$Ei(z) = -\gamma - \log z - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-z)^k}{k k!} \,,$$

and so has a logarithmic branch point at $z=0$. Near infinity I believe we have $Ei(z) \sim \frac{e^z}{z}$ and so an essential singularity at infinity. We note that $Ei'(z) = e^z/z$ is non-zero except at $z=-\infty$ and so the inverse function $Ei^{-1}(z)$ should be holomorphic except at $z=0$.

I am interested in the nature of the singularity of $Ei^{-1}(z)$ at $z=0$ and the asymptotics of it's coefficients. Let $f(z):= Ei^{-1}(1-z)$. By definition $f(z)$ satisfies the following non-linear ODE:

$$f'(z) = -f(z) e^{-f(z)} \,, \text{with} f(\infty) = 0 \,.$$

Can we argue generally about what kind of singularities this ODE has? Using the ODE I can recursively compute the Taylor series coefficients of $f(z)$ about $z=0$. If I plot the ratios $|(n+1)f^{n}(0)/f^{n+1}(0)|$ I find the quite unexpected:

[image: Ratio test]

which, at least to this numerical order, seems inconsistent with having a positive radius of convergence there. I appreciate any comments that can shed light on the singularities of this function!

Comment: What is $Ei^{-1}(z)$? $z = 0$ is a logarithimic branching point!

Comment: @Dieter excuse my ignorance but can we not did a branch and ask for a local inverse? E.g. I’d be happy saying the inverse of log in the principal branch is exp?

Comment: Failing that, define as a unique local solution to the initial value problem above and then take the unique analytic continuation ?

Comment: Or phrased differently, when I iteratively compute derivatives of this ODE and evaluate at different points, I am surely computing local power series of some function

Comment: Why "I am interested in the nature of the singularity of $Ei^{-1}(z)$ at $z=0$ and the asymptotics of it's coefficients" but "Let $f(z):= Ei^{-1}(1-z)$ [...]  I can recursively compute the Taylor series coefficients of $f(z)$ about $z=0$"? Why do you insert $1-$ in $f(z):= Ei^{-1}(1-z)$?

Comment: That was clumsy of me, I made a typo and meant to write the ODE for Ei^-1. This shouldn’t change the point of the question, thanks for pointing out - will edit

Comment: There's something wrong with the statement of the problem: there is a (unique) $x_0 > 0$ such that $Ei(x_0) = 0$, and so the principal branch of the inverse $Ei^{-1}$ is a nice analytic function near $0$. The same applies to other branches ($Ei$ has countably many zeroes). So why do you expect that $Ei^{-1}$ has a singularity at zero?

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki thanks for your comment. Perhaps I was being silly but I was applying the inverse function theorem to $Ei$ and arguing that the derivative is zero near $z=-\infty$ where there is also a zero.

Comment: @SamuelCrew: Ah, sorry, now I see what you mean, you invert $Ei(z)$ near the asymptotic zero at $z = -\infty$. But then shouldn't the condition for $f$ read $f(1) = -\infty$? Also $Ei(z)$ is negative for negative $z$, so would it not be more reasonable to consider $f(z) = Ei^{-1}(-1+z)$ instead?

Comment: Yes ok, I agree with both these points--thanks.

Comment: Are you using the Ei$(x),x<0$ branch?